# Bypassing user name and password in reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have created a software in VB 2008 usind crystal report 2008 for the reports. The software is a network application, when I try to access a report from the client machine it asks for the User name and password; but on the server nothing is requested. I used ODBC connectivity. 
Therefore I want to know how to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your client application and the server apps resides on different networks then you needs to check the permissions for the client machine/user to access the report path